# ROS2 control launch freeze

Tags: ros2, launch-file, ros2-control

I have just gotten my first diffdrive hardware interface to run, connected to a RPi Pico running Micro-ROS. My launch file is pretty much identical to the demo:

[ROS2 Control diffbot demo launch file](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/humble/example_2/bringup/launch/diffbot.launch.py)

, except for package name, logging levels etc.

My problem is that in most launch attempts

```
ros2 launch diffbot_pico diffbot.launch.py
```

, the launch process "hangs" until `Ctrl+C` at the `joint_state_broadcaster` node:

```
[spawner-3] [DEBUG] [1696274031.543300764] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: requester: making request: controller_manager_msgs.srv.SwitchController_Request(activate_controllers=['joint_state_broadcaster'], deactivate_controllers=[], start_controllers=[], stop_controllers=[], strictness=2, start_asap=False, activate_asap=True, timeout=builtin_interfaces.msg.Duration(sec=5, nanosec=0))
[spawner-3] 
[spawner-3] [DEBUG] [1696274031.543453746] [rcl]: Client sending service request
[spawner-3] [DEBUG] [1696274031.544023770] [rcl]: Initializing wait set with '0' subscriptions, '2' guard conditions, '0' timers, '4' clients, '6' services
```

After `n` launch attempts, the broadcaster activation suddenly succeeds, and the launch procedure goes on to activate the `diffbot_base_controller` etc. On those occasions, RVIZ is opened as expected, and all communication to Micro-ROS/ microcontroller is OK.

```
[spawner-3] [DEBUG] [1696274031.720523369] [rcl]: Client taking service response
[spawner-3] [DEBUG] [1696274031.720603413] [rcl]: Client take response succeeded: true
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1696274031.722087080] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
....
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but these errors show up early in the launch log:

```
[spawner-3] [DEBUG] [1696274031.151595044] [rcl]: Couldn't parse arg 0 (/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner) as a remap rule in its deprecated form. Error: Expected lexeme type (19) not found, search ended at index 46, at ./src/rcl/lexer_lookahead.c:239
[spawner-3] [DEBUG] [1696274031.151611839] [rcl]: Couldn't parse arg 1 (joint_state_broadcaster) as a remap rule in its deprecated form. Error: Expected lexeme type (19) not found, search ended at index 23, at ./src/rcl/lexer_lookahead.c:239
[spawner-3] [DEBUG] [1696274031.151615583] [rcl]: Couldn't parse arg 2 (--controller-manager) as a remap rule in its deprecated form. Error: Expecting token or wildcard, at ./src/rcl/arguments.c:1170
[spawner-3] [DEBUG] [1696274031.151618769] [rcl]: Couldn't parse arg 3 (/controller_manager) as a remap rule in its deprecated form. Error: Expected lexeme type (19) not found, search ended at index 19, at ./src/rcl/lexer_lookahead.c:239
```

I also got the debugger module connected to the Pico, and when the launch file hangs, there is NO TX/RX indication (LED). On succesful attempts, the TX/RX indicators immediately indicate traffic.

Anyone having related experience in this kind of arbitrary launch error?

Comment: Hi. Could you please add information on which release you are using? You link to the master branch of the demos, do you use iron or rolling?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I am using Humble

Comment: ok, that should not change anything regarding the controller_manager or spawner.

Comment: can you explain your architecture more in detail? I never worked with micro-ROS, where do you launch the controller_node of ros2_control? Where is the data transferred from your PC to micro-ROS?

Comment: I took inspiration from the ROSCON 22 workshop code, and the work of Josh Newman, and have a separate `comms` header file. In there, I initialize some ROS2 publishers, and a ROS2 client, using the custom interfaces installed both on the ROS2 workspace, and in the micro-ROS workspace on the Pico. It's more or less the same code as found in the ROS2 tutorials, for writing custom publisher and custom client. The communication is managed via a micro-ROS agent, running in a Docker container on the client/ host PC. Happy to share my work, when it's less buggy :)

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand your question, the `control_node` is defined and launched in the launch file, just like in the official example.

Comment: So you publish/subscribe standard ROS 2 messages from your hardware interface? Which means you have a node inside? This is nothing we'd suggest for the hardware interfaces because it can break the realtime loop. But if timing is not that important, this is still fine. I haven't used it, but maybe you can reuse https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/topic_based_ros2_control?

Comment: In principle, I have followed the dummy comms setup from ROSCON workshop: https://github.com/ros-controls/roscon2022_workshop/blob/master/controlko_hardware_interface/include/controlko_hardware_interface/dr_denis_rrbot_comms.hpp , but added a "real" ROS2 node. was not aware of this being a problem. I will have a look on the package you linked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the debug log-level a lot, normally I was able to solve such problems with the standard Info/Warn/Error messages.

I suggest the following:

- Change your launch file to a minimum, i.e., do not activate any controllers (outcomment the spawners) and launch it.
- Use the [ros2_control CLI](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control/ros2controlcli/doc/userdoc.html) to introspect the controller manager's state. The CLI commands are only python wrappers for the services provided by the controller manager. If there is a problem, you will also see this with the CLI commands.
- Follow the points from literal 6 of [RRbot example_1](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_1/doc/userdoc.html) (load controller, configure, activate) and see if you can reproduce and isolate your issue.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer, I will look at your suggestions tomorrow